# TTFB taking 2 mins on some pages

Tags: networking, web-server, apache2, slow-connection

We have a server that has recently gotten into an issue where the TTFB (Time To First Byte) takes 2.0 minutes to pass on some subpages of a website. Some other websites, hosted on the same server, does not experience. The wierd part is that when this is happening it seems to be always 2 minutes, hinting something is timing out, but the response is 200.

[image: TTFB on affected site]

What could be causing this extremely long TTFB ?

The webserver is a Ubuntu version 10.04 running Apache 2 with PHP 5.3.2

Comment: Anything in PHP / Apache log files? You should also upgrade your PHP, that version is ancient snd prone to security issues.

Comment: Logs didn't show anything it seemed and yes this is indeed a very old server, but there is currently no intention of getting it updated I'm afraid (boss decision).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this problem was a wrong DNS setting in the network interfaces configuration file in linux.

The first DNS entry was to a server which was offline. Removing this and relying on googles DNS solved the problem completely. However im still not sure why it would only affect certain subpages on some sites.

Comment: hi @daniel can you explain a bit further, i seem to have a similar issue, but am new to linux

Comment: @Naval - You need to figure out how to update your servers DNS settings. What was causing this for us, was that the server the site was hosted on, had set a DNS server that did not exist. If you change your servers DNS settings to, say googles (8.8.8.8) it might fix it for you

Comment: Thanks @daniel it helped